# HTML template for Custom Content Type

Tags: nodes

I'm reasonably new to Drupal... I've known about it for quite a number of years and have played around with it in the past, but only in the past 4 months have I started to make a serious website with it. Possibly a bit harder to configure than say WordPress, but so much more worth it when it's finished!

One thing that I'm trying to do is work with custom content types. What I am trying to do is create a custom content type called "Talk." In this I want to be able to specify a small description, an embed video URL and a link to PDF notes. I am having a really hard time to try and work out how to do that, and be able to customise it in a way I want.

What I want ultimately to be able to do is specify a HTML template for a custom field. That HTML then specifies where the fields appear (which may become problematic when there can be an undetermined number of entries for a particular field, but there could always be some way.)

Basically, let's say I specified the following

```
Summary: This is my summary
Embed: http://player.vimeo.com/video/51254497?title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=1
Notes: http://link/to/notes.pdf
```

I then want to be able to take those values and put them somewhere in HTML. For example...

```
<iframe src="" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="[Embed]" allowfullscreen=""></iframe><br>
<em>[Summary]</em><br>
<a href="[Notes]">Download corresponding notes</a>
```

Is there any way that I can create a custom content type that would give me that much control over my field? I've had a look but haven't been able to find any way, even with a module (though there's a good chance I haven't seen the right module!)

Thanks for any help,
Josh.

Comment: What all methods have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think your looking into this a bit too deep for what it is.

For your fields you use the following:

- Summary: Default field with any content type
- Embed: http://drupal.org/project/youtube (not sure if theres something for
  vimeo)
- Notes: Create a field that accepts PDf file extension

You then have loads of options for how you can present your content type. How about just creating a template file for that content type so...

```
node--type.tpl.php
```

You can then manipulate the output of the fields, for example...

```
<div class="somewhere-over-there">
    print render($content['youtube_field']);
</div>

<div class="somewhere-down-there">
    print render($content['pdf_field']);
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. A combination of your answer and this video helped me do what I wanted: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s. I ended up altering each field individually (so field--field_vimeo.tpl.php allowed me to just specify the Vimeo video ID and I could put the embed code there.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique page.tpl.php for a content type.

in your template.php file, add the following:

`function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node_' . $variables['node']->type;
    $nodetype = 'page__node_' . $variables['node']->type; 
}`

You can then create a template file:  page--node-contenttype.tpl.php

If your content type was "talk" it would be:  page--node-talk.tpl.php